# Open custom url from vscode

Tags: hyperlink, visual-studio-code

I'd like to create a shortcut to open a custom link generated using the selected text from the current editor. So far I tried:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "workbench.action.url.openUrl",
        "args": {
          "text": "https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/${selectedText}"
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
```

with no success.
Is it possible?